# How to multiply two values with the same key name from different linkedHashMaps?

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have two linkedHashmaps which are the same length with the same key names but the values are different. for example :

```
Map<String, Double> map1= new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>(); 

map1.put("A", 2.3);    
map1.put("B", 6.1);
map1.put("C", 5.3);

Map<String, Double> map2= new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>(); 

map2.put("A", 10.3);    
map2.put("B", 60.1);
map2.put("C", 0.3);
```

How would I multiply each value from map1 with the same corresponding key in       map2 (A 2.3*10.3, B 6.1*60.1 etc etc) and save the results to a new linkedHashMap?

I tried this with no luck.

```
Map<String, Double> map3= new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
                double valueMap1 = map1.get(key);
                double valueMap2 = map2.get(key1);

            for(String key : map1.keySet())
                for(String key1 : map2.keySet()){
            if(map1.containsKey(key1)){


                double newValue =valueMap1* valueMap2;


                map3.put(key1, newValue);
        }
      }
```

Comment: With bare hand, what did you try?

Comment: The solution is very simple, please explain what have you tried and where did you fail. If you haven't tried anything first then go try and if it didn't work then ask

Comment: Is the order of keys in your two linkedhashmaps the same? Then you can get values of sorted maps as list and make required multiplications, saving the values to new list, and then combine keys and values.

Comment: @MichaelGantman  I have added what I tried to no success, I'm relatively new to maps so I feel pretty lost with this problem.

Comment: You should not use a  nested loop. Only one loop for this task.

Comment: If the keys are the same, simply use the outer for loop key. Also, I think you want to get rid of the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the loop that should solve your problem

```
Map<String, Double> map3= new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
for(String key : map1.keySet()) {
    if(map2.containsKey(key)) {
       map3.put(key, map1.get(key) * map2.get(key);
    }
}
```